# Can't access value in object when using value for inline styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm querying data from firebase with the following code:

```js
// query for profile, link, and theme data
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
     
      db.collection("users")
        .doc(user)
        .collection("theme")
        .doc(user)
        .onSnapshot(function (doc) {
          setSelectedTheme(doc.data());
          console.log("Theme Data: ", doc.data());
        });
    } else {
      setProfile([]);
    }
  }, [user]);
```

This function sets the query values in my db to my `selectedThemes`variable.

This is how the data prints in my console:

[image]

Now, when I use try to use the value `selectedTheme.background.backgroundImage` in my inline styling:

```js
 const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundImage: `url("${selectedTheme.background.backgroundImage}")`,
 
  };
```

I get the following error: `Cannot read property 'backgroundImage' of undefined`

Comment: Is it possible you are trying to access that state before it comes back from your ajax call?

Comment: The data retrieval is asynchronous, this means while the data is being retrieved the `selectedTheme` is undefined. You must wait until the data is retrieved to use the data. A simple fix for this might be a fallback style i.e. `backgroundImage: selectedTheme ? 'url("${selectedTheme.background.backgroundImage}")' : undefined`

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example. From these two snippets we've no idea if they are even in the same unit of code, and if they are, what happens between them. Either way, the error is telling you that `selectedTheme.background` is undefined, so looking for where that value is set is probably a good place to start debugging.